# Incrementing database with button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table called posts. And in it I have a column called vote that is an integer.

In my posts_controller I have:

```
  def upvote
    @post = Post.find params[:id]
    @post.votes = @post.votes +1
  end
```

In my view I have

```
  <%= link_to 'like', upvote(post.id)%>
```

And in my routes I have

```
  resources :posts do
    member do
      put :upvote
    end
  end
```

Every time the user clicks like I want it to go up +1. I keep getting an error:

> undefined method `upvote' for #<#:0x007fc180f8d650>

It highlights this line

```
 <%= link_to 'like', upvote(post.id)%>
```

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Run ```rake routes``` command, most likely your upvote methods are ```posts_upvote_path``` and ```posts_upvote_url```

Comment: @Matt : for voting system you can try `act_as_votable` gem which is very easy to integrate and use as per your requirement. here is it's link https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable

Answer (score 3):

You need to do a couple things.

1. Use the correct route. Where you have `upvote(post.id)`, it should be `upvote_post_url(post.id)`. Learn more about route helpers [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers).
2. Your controller action `upvote` needs to modify the passed in post. Rails has some a [built in counter incrementer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-increment_counter) to help with this. It will save you from any race conditions if more than one like is added to the same post.

   ```
   def upvote
     Post.increment_counter(:votes, params[:id])
   end
   ```

I suggest also following a Ruby on Rails tutorial to help you get started. [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/) is a fun one.

Answer (score 0):

Further to `yez's` answer, you'll also need to change the [`method` of your `link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to):

```
<%= link_to 'like', posts_upvote_path(post), method: :put %>
```

You'll also want to improve your routes (all routes are `member` routes by default):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :posts do
   put :upvote
end
```

You'll also be more suited to using the [`increment!`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment%21) method (which is basically the same as yez's `increment_counter` but more succinct):

```
def upvote
  @post = Post.find params[:id]
  @post.increment! :votes
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have my model, controller and view set up live you've said. I keep getting Couldn't find Post with 'id'= error. Any ideas?